# Xcode - replace navigation bar with toolbar on show segue

Tags: ios, interface-builder, toolbar

This is what I wish to do.

[image: segue : Push] ---- Segue : show ---->[image]

on the destination page, I want to **hide the tab bar** from the previous page and **show the toolbar** instead.

When I check "Hide bottom bar on push" on storyboard, the tool bar on the destination page disappears as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the title of your question since you want to replace the tabBar with a toolBar and keep the navigationBar. At leas this is what I understand from your sketch.

As for the question, have you tried hiding the tabBar in viewWillDisappear in your first view?